# Sorting current-group() by child node element and get the result

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nlp

it's me again. Sorry but this time i have a more important question for you guys.
Here is the xml :

```
<titre>
<p type="titre">
<item><a>1</a><a>Ce</a><a>ce</a><a>PRO</a><a>PRO</a><a>n=s</a><a>0</a><a>_</a><a>0</a><a>_</a></item>
<item><a>2</a><a>que</a><a>que</a><a>PROREL</a><a>PROREL</a><a></a><a>5</a><a>obj</a><a>5</a><a>obj</a></item>
<item><a>3</a><a>l'</a><a>le</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s</a><a>4</a><a>det</a><a>4</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>4</a><a>on</a><a>on</a><a>CLS</a><a>CLS</a><a>n=s|p=3</a><a>5</a><a>suj</a><a>5</a><a>suj</a></item>
<item><a>5</a><a>sait</a><a>savoir</a><a>V</a><a>V</a><a>n=s|t=P|p=3</a><a>1</a><a>mod_rel</a><a>1</a><a>mod_rel</a></item>
<item><a>6</a><a>de</a><a>de</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>5</a><a>mod</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>7</a><a>l'</a><a>le</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s</a><a>8</a><a>det</a><a>8</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>8</a><a>attentat</a><a>attentat</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>6</a><a>prep</a><a>6</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>9</a><a>du</a><a>de</a><a>P+D</a><a>P+D</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>10</a><a>Nouvel</a><a>_</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a></a><a>11</a><a>mod</a><a>11</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>11</a><a>An</a><a>An</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a>n=s</a><a>9</a><a>prep</a><a>9</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>12</a><a>dans</a><a>dans</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>5</a><a>mod</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>13</a><a>un</a><a>un</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>14</a><a>det</a><a>14</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>14</a><a>club</a><a>club</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>12</a><a>prep</a><a>12</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>15</a><a>d'</a><a>de</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>5</a><a>mod</a><a>5</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>16</a><a>Istanbul</a><a>_</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a></a><a>15</a><a>prep</a><a>15</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>17</a><a>.</a><a>.</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>16</a><a>ponct</a><a>16</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>18</a><a>§</a><a>§</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>16</a><a>ponct</a><a>16</a><a>ponct</a></item>
</p>
</titre>
<titre>
<p type="titre">
<item><a>1</a><a>Tiers</a><a>tiers</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>g=m</a><a>0</a><a>_</a><a>0</a><a>_</a></item>
<item><a>2</a><a>payant</a><a>payant</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>3</a><a>,</a><a>,</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>2</a><a>ponct</a><a>2</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>4</a><a>paquet</a><a>paquet</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>5</a><a>neutre</a><a>neutre</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>6</a><a>,</a><a>,</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>5</a><a>ponct</a><a>5</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>7</a><a>divorce</a><a>divorce</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>8</a><a>…</a><a>…</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>7</a><a>ponct</a><a>7</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>9</a><a>ce</a><a>ce</a><a>PRO</a><a>PRO</a><a>n=s</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>10</a><a>qui</a><a>qui</a><a>PROREL</a><a>PROREL</a><a>n=s</a><a>11</a><a>suj</a><a>11</a><a>suj</a></item>
<item><a>11</a><a>change</a><a>changer</a><a>V</a><a>V</a><a>n=s|t=P,S|p=1,3</a><a>9</a><a>mod_rel</a><a>9</a><a>mod_rel</a></item>
<item><a>12</a><a>en</a><a>en</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>11</a><a>mod</a><a>11</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>13</a><a>janvier</a><a>janvier</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>12</a><a>prep</a><a>12</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>14</a><a>2017</a><a>2017</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a></a><a>13</a><a>mod</a><a>13</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>15</a><a>.</a><a>.</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>14</a><a>ponct</a><a>14</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>16</a><a>§</a><a>§</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>14</a><a>ponct</a><a>14</a><a>ponct</a></item>
</p>
</titre>
<description>
<p type="description">
<item><a>1</a><a>CETA</a><a>_</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a></a><a>9</a><a>suj</a><a>9</a><a>suj</a></item>
<item><a>2</a><a>,</a><a>,</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>1</a><a>ponct</a><a>1</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>3</a><a>TPP</a><a>_</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a></a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>4</a><a>,</a><a>,</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>3</a><a>ponct</a><a>3</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>5</a><a>Tafta</a><a>_</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a></a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>6</a><a>...</a><a>...</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>5</a><a>ponct</a><a>5</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>7</a><a>2016</a><a>2016</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a></a><a>1</a><a>mod</a><a>1</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>8</a><a>a</a><a>avoir</a><a>V</a><a>V</a><a>n=s|t=P|p=3</a><a>9</a><a>aux_tps</a><a>9</a><a>aux_tps</a></item>
<item><a>9</a><a>porté</a><a>porter</a><a>VPP</a><a>VPP</a><a>n=s|g=m|t=K</a><a>0</a><a>root</a><a>0</a><a>root</a></item>
<item><a>10</a><a>au</a><a>à</a><a>P+D</a><a>P+D</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>9</a><a>mod</a><a>9</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>11</a><a>libre</a><a>libre</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s</a><a>13</a><a>mod</a><a>13</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>12</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>11</a><a>ponct</a><a>11</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>13</a><a>échange</a><a>échanger</a><a>V</a><a>V</a><a>n=s|t=P,S|p=1,3</a><a>9</a><a>mod</a><a>9</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>14</a><a>un</a><a>un</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>15</a><a>det</a><a>15</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>15</a><a>coup</a><a>coup</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>13</a><a>obj</a><a>13</a><a>obj</a></item>
<item><a>16</a><a>dont</a><a>dont</a><a>PROREL</a><a>PROREL</a><a></a><a>18</a><a>obj</a><a>18</a><a>obj</a></item>
<item><a>17</a><a>il</a><a>il</a><a>CLS</a><a>CLS</a><a>n=s|g=m|p=3</a><a>18</a><a>suj</a><a>18</a><a>suj</a></item>
<item><a>18</a><a>pourrait</a><a>pouvoir</a><a>V</a><a>V</a><a>n=s|t=C|p=3</a><a>15</a><a>mod_rel</a><a>15</a><a>mod_rel</a></item>
<item><a>19</a><a>garder</a><a>garder</a><a>VINF</a><a>VINF</a><a>t=W</a><a>18</a><a>obj</a><a>18</a><a>obj</a></item>
<item><a>20</a><a>pour</a><a>pour</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>19</a><a>mod</a><a>19</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>21</a><a>longtemps</a><a>longtemps</a><a>ADV</a><a>ADV</a><a></a><a>23</a><a>mod</a><a>23</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>22</a><a>des</a><a>des</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=p</a><a>23</a><a>det</a><a>23</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>23</a><a>séquelles</a><a>séquelle</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=p|g=f</a><a>20</a><a>prep</a><a>20</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>24</a><a>.</a><a>.</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>23</a><a>ponct</a><a>23</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>25</a><a>§</a><a>§</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>23</a><a>ponct</a><a>23</a><a>ponct</a></item>
</p>
</description>
<description>
<p type="description">
<item><a>1</a><a>L'</a><a>le</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s</a><a>4</a><a>det</a><a>4</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>2</a><a>ancien</a><a>ancien</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>3</a><a>premier</a><a>premier</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>4</a><a>ministre</a><a>ministre</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=m</a><a>7</a><a>suj</a><a>7</a><a>suj</a></item>
<item><a>5</a><a>socialiste</a><a>socialiste</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>n=s</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>6</a><a>portugais</a><a>portugais</a><a>ADJ</a><a>ADJ</a><a>g=m</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a><a>4</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>7</a><a>succède</a><a>succéder</a><a>V</a><a>V</a><a>n=s|t=P,S|p=1,3</a><a>0</a><a>root</a><a>0</a><a>root</a></item>
<item><a>8</a><a>à</a><a>à</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>7</a><a>mod</a><a>7</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>9</a><a>Ban</a><a>_</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a></a><a>8</a><a>prep</a><a>8</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>10</a><a>Ki</a><a>_</a><a>NPP</a><a>NPP</a><a></a><a>9</a><a>mod</a><a>9</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>11</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>10</a><a>ponct</a><a>10</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>12</a><a>moon</a><a>_</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a></a><a>9</a><a>mod</a><a>9</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>13</a><a>à</a><a>à</a><a>P</a><a>P</a><a></a><a>7</a><a>mod</a><a>7</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>14</a><a>la</a><a>la</a><a>DET</a><a>DET</a><a>n=s|g=f</a><a>15</a><a>det</a><a>15</a><a>det</a></item>
<item><a>15</a><a>tête</a><a>tête</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=s|g=f</a><a>13</a><a>prep</a><a>13</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>16</a><a>des</a><a>de</a><a>P+D</a><a>P+D</a><a>n=p</a><a>15</a><a>dep</a><a>15</a><a>dep</a></item>
<item><a>17</a><a>Nations</a><a>nation</a><a>NC</a><a>NC</a><a>n=p|g=f</a><a>16</a><a>prep</a><a>16</a><a>prep</a></item>
<item><a>18</a><a>unies</a><a>unir</a><a>VPP</a><a>VPP</a><a>n=p|g=f|t=K</a><a>17</a><a>mod</a><a>17</a><a>mod</a></item>
<item><a>19</a><a>.</a><a>.</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>18</a><a>ponct</a><a>18</a><a>ponct</a></item>
<item><a>20</a><a>§</a><a>§</a><a>PONCT</a><a>PONCT</a><a></a><a>18</a><a>ponct</a><a>18</a><a>ponct</a></item>
</p>
</description>
```

nodes items are tokens with POS, dependencies etc...
I would like to keep only the nodes item where a[8] = 'obj' and i would like to sort my item by a[4], ascending. Here is my piece of code but it doesn't work. The items contains only elements with a[8]='obj' but the sort doesn't work. And i would like to concatenate a[2] and a[4] to have the word ans his POS (part of speech) How do you do that ? How to keep the nodes sorted from the template ? So my items have to be grouped by a[4] (POS), contains obj in a[8] (dependancie) and be sorted by a[4] ascending. Thx. My output must be like this :

```
de  DET  
garcon NC    
qui PRONREL  
marcher V
```

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>    
    
<xsl:template match="/">
    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//titre"/>
     
</xsl:template>      
    <xsl:template match="titre">
        
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p//item[a[8]='obj']" group-by="a[4]">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(a[2], ' ', a[4])"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        
    </xsl:template>

    
<xsl:template match="description">
    
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have this output :

```
que PROREL  
faire VINF   
année NC   
pays NC   
l' CLO   
à P   
revenu NC  
vœux NC   
retenir VINF  
An NPP  
ans NC   
amuser VINF  
relance NC  
soutien NC  
objet NC   
identité NC  
débat NC   
être  VINF     
NC artiste  
cours NC     
hausse NC     
zone NC
```

Comment: It is not clear why you need a variable and where do you expect the `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">` to be pushed to, you don't have any template matching `item` elements. Doesn't it suffice to use `<xsl:for-each select="current-group()"><xsl:sort select="a[4]"/><xsl:value-of select="a[2], a[4]"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each>`?

Comment: If you wanted a variable you could use `<xsl:variable name="sorted-items" as="element(item)*"><xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()"><xsl:sort select="a[4]"/></xsl:perform-sort></xsl:variable>`.

Comment: <xsl:for-each-group select="//item[a[8]='obj']" Wil select all items from root.  Is that want you want?

Comment: It doesn't work. My grouping and my sort must be here  `<xsl:for-each-group select="p//item[a[8]='obj']" group-by="a[4]">`

Comment: Can you show us the code without sorting, that for the posted input sample, outputs the four lines you have shown, even if not in the right order?

Comment: Why does the code in the question have `<xsl:for-each-group select="//item[a[8]='obj']"` while your comment says you want `<xsl:for-each-group select="p//item[a[8]='obj']"`? If the grouping is not even working as intended it is hard for use to suggest how to sort the grouped items.

Comment: i have the following output
que PROREL  
faire VINF  
année NC  
pays NC  
l' CLO  
à P  
revenu NC 
vœux NC  
retenir VINF  
An NPP  
ans NC  
amuser VINF  
relance NC  
soutien NC  
objet NC  
identité NC  
débat NC  
être VINF  
artiste NC  
cours NC  
hausse NC  
zone NC
i dunno how to do breaklines

Comment: So which code gives that output you have shown for the input you have posted? If your grouping works and you say with sorting you want four lines of text in the order `de  DET`, `garcon NC`, `qui PRONREL`, `marcher V` I don't understand why your existing code produces more than 20 lines.

Comment: Done. It's weird no ?

Comment: the ouput code i gave in example is just a sample. I want my words sorted by their POS ascending.

Comment: it's exactly the same output with or without grouping... is it a key problem ?

Comment: Your current XSLT, run against your input sample (had to wrap into a `root` element) gives exactly one line: `que PROREL`. As I said previously, cut down your samples to be minimal but representative and focus on one issue. If you have grouping working and want to add sorting, fine, but if you later say "it's exactly the same output with or without grouping" it seems you haven't really prepared minimal but complete and consistent samples to allow us to understand the problem.

Comment: Okay i lunched the debugger an this line is the problem `<xsl:for-each-group select="p//item[a[8]='obj']" group-by="a[4]">` it never execute the code in the loop

Comment: How to manage this issue ? I use Oxygen and Saxon 3.9

Comment: I am afraid we haven't resolved anything so far. And your explanations and comments don't help, the question was about sorting the results of grouping, now you say you want to debug XSLT with oXygen and Saxon, but give a version `3.9` of Saxon that seems so odd given that Saxon 6.5.5 is the XSLT 1 version of Saxon and the current versions for XSLT 3 are Saxon 9.9 or 10.5. Take it step by step, the oXygen guys have helpful videos and a community of its own where you can ask to familiarize yourself with the debugger.

Comment: Perhaps it will also be easier for you to get help in a French speaking forum like https://www.developpez.net/forums/f461/autres-langages/xml-xsl-soap/xsl-xslt-xpath/ as there people might better understand your samples and you don't have to translate your descriptions or requirements. I just mention that as an option, feel free to ask in English on StackOverflow if you prefer that, but make sure you make it as easy as possible to help by posting separate issues as separate questions and by always providing minimal but complete and consistent code samples.

Comment: is it so difficult to understand me ? The stackoverflow community is much avec active than developpez.net. Although I sometimes ask questions there.

Comment: it's because my template match=titre so i get the nodes of items where a[8] = 'obj' for one titre but in each titre, there are until 2 or 3 obj no more so the sort is done in these nodes. Isn't it ?

Comment: I do understand the text of your question but I am not able to recognize from your poorly indented, lengthy and foreign language sample data and sample result what you want to achieve. And as I said, if you have working grouping code and need help adding sorting, then post the working grouping code together with minimal, representative input and result samples, then add your attempt to sort together with an exact error message or the wrong output and I am sure people can help. But don't expect us to suddenly switch to debugging your grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `for-each` and `for-each-group` allow you to apply sorting by using `xsl:sort` so if you want to order the groups use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//p[@type='titre']//item[a[8]='obj']" group-by="a[4]">
  <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
```

if you want to output the items in each group use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
  <xsl:sort select="a[2]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found by myself the solution. The grouping by a[4] works. I know that this code is pretty awful but i can't handle with templates for the moment. I can't do that. Although, if you have some improvements (they are many ones) to suggest, please let me now. I would like to use templates to split the code.
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>    
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <xsl:comment>This code is awful but it works</xsl:comment>
        
        <xsl:text>**************  Titres (titles) ***************</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Elements with obj dependancies : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//p[@type='titre']//item[a[8]='obj'])"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//p[@type='titre']//item[a[8]='obj']" group-by="a[4]">
            <xsl:text>Total number of words in the category</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(current-group()/a[4])"/>
            <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat(a[2], ' ', a[4])"/>
                 <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        
        <xsl:text>************ Descriptions *************</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Elements with obj dependancies : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//p[@type='description']//item[a[8]='obj'])"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//p[@type='description']//item[a[8]='obj']" group-by="a[4]">
            <xsl:text>Number of words in the category </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(current-group()/a[4])"/>
            <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(a[2], ' ', a[4])"/>
                <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        
    </xsl:template>
          
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the following output is what i want. Is it possible th sort also the categories (a[4]) by order ascending ? I precise that the result is concerns the entire xml file :

```
 **************  Titres (titles) ***************

Elements with obj dependancies : 16

Number of words in the category  PROREL : 1
que PROREL

Number of words in the category  VINF : 2
faire VINF
retenir VINF

Number of words in the category  NC : 11
année NC
revenu NC
vœux NC
relance NC
soutien NC
objet NC
identité NC
débat NC
cours NC
hausse NC
zone NC

Number of words in the category  P : 1
à P

Number of words in the category  NPP : 1
An NPP

************ Descriptions *************

Elements with obj dependancies : 14

Number of words in the category NC : 12
entrée NC
coup NC
actualité NC
début NC
Etat NC
euros NC
Français NC
bal NC
lieu NC
monde NC
problèmes NC
morts NC

Number of words in the category PROREL : 1
dont PROREL

Number of words in the category VINF : 1
garder VINF
```